# how to unlock my ethereum private network account in geth version 1.10.16

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, private-blockchain, truffle-migration

when I try to unlock my Ethereum private network account in go-Ethereum version 1.10.16, it show error like this, how could I overcome this?

Error:
`Error: account unlock with HTTP access is forbidden at web3.js:6365:37(47) at github.com/Ethereum/go-Ethereum/internal/jsre.MakeCallback.func1 (native) at :1:24(3)`

I tried to install different types of web3.js but still I can't clear this issue

Comment: don't unlock that is bad practice. use the private key to sign transactions

Comment: @MajdTL when I migrate my contract using private network it ask me to unlock you're account. I also add my private key at truffle config file. still it ask me to unlock my account for migration.